# 301 redirect adds double slash within new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble setting up a 301 redirect within Apache.  I am looking to automatically redirect anyone who visits pages at the old domain to go to the new domain (with one exception: it will not redirect a particular subfolder).  Here is what I have right now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So right now, the exception works fine - anytime I go to any page under that subfolder such as

```
http://www.olddomain.com/subfolder/temp_page.html
```

it will maintain the original URL and not redirect, as I wanted.

But when I go to any page outside of that subfolder, the redirect will add a double slash to the new URL.  For example, if I go to

```
http://www.olddomain.com/temp_page.html
```

it will redirect it to

```
http://www.newdomain.com//temp_page.html
```

I have tried various suggested fixes on here and other sites - but nothing seems to be working.  Any help you could pass along my way would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the excess slash you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R]
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that did it!  I added that to the .htaccess for the new domain and the double slash is gone.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help @NeoTec :)